# Rails table data shows as a hash under the real table data in Browser

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, web

I am trying to display all of the blog posts on the index page, but whenever I go to it, it displays what I want, and then below it, it puts the rest of the data as a hash.  I want the first post and first description to be in the browser but I don't want the hash under it to be in there.
[image: Screenshot of how the data from the table shows up]

This is my posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @post = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end
end

private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

This is my index.html.erb file

```
<h1>Blog Posts</h1>

    <table>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <div><%= @post.each do |post| %></div>
      <tr>
        <td><%= post.title %></td>
        <td><%= post.description %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <% end %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you will find that this line is the source of your issue:

```
<div><%= @post.each do |post| %></div>
```

The `<%= %>` tag in ERB is for outputting the results of the evaluation. You want to just process the loop, for which you use the `<% %>` tag.

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
```

Note the removal of the `=` sign as well as the `<div>`s. You don't need the `<div>` tags since nothing should be output from iterating code.

Also, your HTML **is not valid** - `div` can't be a direct child of `table`. Use like:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @post.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= post.title %></td>
        <td><%= post.description %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.